# Subquery in doctrine's createQuery

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm facing a little issue, and I hope someone can help me with it.
In SQL I have this query which gives me the result I want:

```
SELECT * FROM price_material AS y 
JOIN (
   SELECT * FROM price_material_price GROUP BY id DESC
) AS x 
GROUP BY y.price_material_id
```

Now I tried to translate this to my PHP project:

```
    public function getPriceLines($pricelist = 0, $year = 0, $week = 0)
    {
        if ($year === 0) {
            $year = (int)date('Y');
        }

        if ($week === 0) {
            $week = (int)date('W');
        }

        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
          SELECT pgp FROM ACME\Bundle\PricelistBundle\Entity\PricelistMaterialPrice pgp
          INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM ACME\Bundle\PricelistBundle\Entity\PricelistMaterial ORDER BY id DESC)
          WHERE pr.pricelist = :pricelist AND pgp.year <= :year
          AND pgp.week <= :week
          GROUP BY pgp.pricelistmaterial
          ORDER BY pgp.year DESC, pgp.week DESC, pgp.id DESC
        ')->setParameters(array('pricelist' => $pricelist, 'week' => $week, 'year' => $year));

        $result = $query->getResult();

        return $result;
    }
```

But a subquery in a join isn't possible, as what I think, because this gives me the error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 119 near '"(SELECT * FROM': Error: Class '"' is not defined.
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by thinking a bit different.

This is eventually the function:

```
public function getPriceLines($pricelinematerial = 0, $year = 0, $week = 0)
    {
        if ($year === 0) {
            $year = (int)date('Y');
        }

        if ($week === 0) {
            $week = (int)date('W');
        }

        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
            SELECT pgp FROM ACME\Bundle\PricelistBundle\Entity\PricelistMaterialPrice pgp
            WHERE pgp.pricelistmaterial = :pricelistmaterial AND pgp.year <= :year
            AND pgp.week <= :week
            ORDER BY pgp.year DESC, pgp.week DESC, pgp.id DESC

        ')->setParameters(array('pricelistmaterial' => $pricelistmaterial, 'week' => $week, 'year' => $year));

        $query->setMaxResults(1);
        try {
            $result = $query->getSingleResult();
        } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
            $result = null;
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an unneeded double quote near your subquery:

```
      INNER JOIN "(SELECT * FROM ACME\Bundle\PricelistBundle\Entity\PricelistMaterial ORDER BY id DESC)"
```

instead of

```
      INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM ACME\Bundle\PricelistBundle\Entity\PricelistMaterial ORDER BY id DESC)"
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I actually tried that already. When I remove them, it still gives me a semantical error.

Answer (score 0):

You use `pr.prijslijst` in your `WHERE` clause but you never defined it. I don't understand the language (Dutch?) but if `prijslijst` is a property of `PricelistMaterial` then modifying the subquery like this should work:

```
SELECT pr FROM ACME\Bundle\PricelistBundle\Entity\PricelistMaterial pr ORDER BY pr.id DESC
```

Also, your parameter keys are wrong - they seem to be written in Dutch in the query but in English in the `setParameter` method.

Comment: That was just a little translate mistake from me for SO ;)
pricelist == prijslijst in this case ;)